# Exponential series approximation

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation

I have a series of the following form:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^\infty \left( 1 - e^{-ns^{k-1}} \right)^k
\end{align}
where $0<s<1$. I would like to compute an approximation of this series, for the regime where $n$ is large.

One natural thing to try would be to use the approximation $1-e^{-x} \approx x$, which is valid for small $x$. However, note that we are interested in large $n$, and the dominant terms of the series are those with small $k$, and thus $ns^{k-1}$ is relatively large for this approximation to be accurate. Also, even if it was an accurate approximation, I am not sure how to deal with the doubly exponential term that results from it.

Is there a better way to approximate this? I am particularly interested in a tight lower bound on this series, if it is practical to obtain one.

Comment: i would try euler mac laurin formula and approximate the resulting integral.

Comment: It seems to have an asymptotic like $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \left( 1 - e^{-ns^{k-1}} \right)^k \approx \log \!\left(\frac{1}{s}\right) \Bigl[\log(n) - \log\log\log(n) - 1\Bigr],$$ though I haven't seen a way to obtain this rigorously yet. Numerically this also appears to be missing a term which is very small but may grow with $n$.

Comment: @tired I thought that too, but it seems tricky. I would definitely be interested to see an answer taking that approach.

Comment: @AntonioVargas , ok i will have a look at it when i have mathematica avaiable.

Comment: @AntonioVargas  just out of interest, wich method did u use ?

Comment: @tired, when $k$ is small the terms are very close to $1$, when $k$ is large the terms are very close to $0$, and there is a sharp transition between the two cases. My estimate comes from calculating the value of $k$ where the transition occurs (essentially solving $$\left[1-\exp(-ns^{k-1})\right]^k \approx \left(1 - \frac{a}{k}\right)^k$$ for $k$, say $k = k^*$), and then modeling the sum like $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left[1-\exp(-ns^{k-1})\right]^k \approx \sum_{k=1}^{k^*} 1.$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32883/discussion-between-tired-and-antonio-vargas).

Answer (score 0):

I would rather keep the exponential form and do binomial expansion for say $k\le4$ (you may want to try a different number) and ignore terms for $5<k$. Then the form would be

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(1-e^{-ns^{k-1}}\right)^k&\approx 1-e^{-ns}+1-2e^{-ns^2}+e^{-2ns^2}+1-3e^{-ns^3}+3e^{-2ns^3}-e^{-3ns^3}
\end{align}
I'm not sure how much better this will be than your current approximation but as far as $n$ is a big number, this might help.

Comment: $0<s<1$ as stated in the question

Comment: @tired Yeah. Then we shouldn't use $(1-x)^k\approx 1-kx$. I'll change my answer. Thanks.